# Trouble Connecting to Unity Relay and Lobby Service for Multiplayer Game on the Same Network

Tags: unity-game-engine, network-programming, game-engine, multiplayer

I'm relatively new to working with multiplayer games in Unity, and I've encountered an issue for which I couldn't find a solution. Here's the problem:

I can successfully connect to Unity Relay and Lobby services, and I have no trouble connecting to them individually. However, when two devices on the same network attempt to play together in any lobby, they can't seem to find their lobby or room.

I suspect that the lobby service might be filtering my HostId, possibly to prevent me from seeing my own lobby. However, this filtering seems to have the unintended consequence of preventing LAN (Local Area Network) play.

My question is: How can I modify this filter or attempt to join the same lobby on the same network?

Thank you for taking the time to read this and for any assistance you can provide!

I close relay and use just lobby on my local, try to attemt another network/device. But it doesn't help

I have connect script here:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Netcode;
using Unity.Services.Authentication;
using Unity.Services.Core;
using Unity.Services.Relay;
using Unity.Services.Relay.Models;
using Unity.Netcode.Transports.UTP;
using Unity.Services.Lobbies;
using Unity.Services.Lobbies.Models;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

namespace Edulog.Network
{

public class NetworkConnect : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int maxConnection = 20;
    public UnityTransport transport;

    private Lobby currentLobby;
    private float heartBeatTimer;


    private async void Awake()
    {
        await UnityServices.InitializeAsync();
        await AuthenticationService.Instance.SignInAnonymouslyAsync();


    }

    public async void Create()
    {

        // Connect relay 
        Allocation allocation = await RelayService.Instance.CreateAllocationAsync(maxConnection);

        Debug.Log("Allocation has been done");
        string newJoinCode = await RelayService.Instance.GetJoinCodeAsync(allocation.AllocationId);

        transport.SetHostRelayData(allocation.RelayServer.IpV4, (ushort)allocation.RelayServer.Port,
            allocation.AllocationIdBytes, allocation.Key, allocation.ConnectionData);

        Debug.LogError(newJoinCode);


        // Create lobby on relay


        CreateLobbyOptions lobbyOption = new CreateLobbyOptions();
        lobbyOption.IsPrivate = false;
        lobbyOption.Data = new Dictionary<string, DataObject>();
        DataObject dataObject = new DataObject(DataObject.VisibilityOptions.Public, newJoinCode);
        lobbyOption.Data.Add("JOIN_CODE", dataObject);



        currentLobby = await Lobbies.Instance.CreateLobbyAsync("Lobby Name", maxConnection, lobbyOption);
        Lobby lobbies = await Lobbies.Instance.GetLobbyAsync(currentLobby.Id);
        List<string> tokens = await Lobbies.Instance.GetJoinedLobbiesAsync();


        Debug.LogError(lobbies.Id);
        Debug.LogError("------------");
        foreach (string token in tokens)
        {
            Debug.LogError(token);
        }
        Debug.LogError("------------");

        NetworkManager.Singleton.StartHost();
    }
    public async void JoinOrCreate()
    {
        try
        {

            currentLobby = await Lobbies.Instance.QuickJoinLobbyAsync();
            string relayJoinCode = currentLobby.Data["JOIN_CODE"].Value;
            JoinAllocation allocation = await RelayService.Instance.JoinAllocationAsync(relayJoinCode);

            transport.SetClientRelayData(allocation.RelayServer.IpV4, (ushort)allocation.RelayServer.Port,
                allocation.AllocationIdBytes, allocation.Key, allocation.ConnectionData, allocation.HostConnectionData);



            NetworkManager.Singleton.StartClient();

        }
        catch
        {

            Create();
        }

    }



    public async void QuickJoin()
    {
        currentLobby = await Lobbies.Instance.QuickJoinLobbyAsync();
        string relayJoinCode = currentLobby.Data["JOIN_CODE"].Value;
        JoinAllocation allocation = await RelayService.Instance.JoinAllocationAsync(relayJoinCode);

        transport.SetClientRelayData(allocation.RelayServer.IpV4, (ushort)allocation.RelayServer.Port,
            allocation.AllocationIdBytes, allocation.Key, allocation.ConnectionData, allocation.HostConnectionData);



        NetworkManager.Singleton.StartClient();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (heartBeatTimer > 15)
        {
            heartBeatTimer -= 15;
            if (currentLobby != null && currentLobby.HostId == AuthenticationService.Instance.PlayerId)
                LobbyService.Instance.SendHeartbeatPingAsync(currentLobby.Id);

        }
        heartBeatTimer = Time.deltaTime;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.